# Split a string and return greatest in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-comparison

I need to find a way to get the data with the highest versionNumber.

Here is my database design:

```
VERSIONNUMBER - varchar(15)
DOWNLOADPATH - varchar(100)
```

Lets say I have records like:

```
VERSIONNUMBER -------- DOWNLOADPATH
1.1.2                  a.com
1.1.3                  b.com
2.1.4                  c.com
2.1.5                  d.com
2.2.1                  e.com
```

I need to get the record with the versionnumber 2.2.1. Need some help with the sql though :)

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
    ('1.1.2'),('1.1.3'),('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)
)
select c, PARSENAME(c,1),PARSENAME(c,2), PARSENAME(c,3)
from a
order by 
convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)),
convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)),
convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1))
```

Inspired from: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/sort-ip-address.aspx

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
    ('1.1.2'),('1.1.3'),('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)
),
x as 
(
    select c, 
       convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)) * 100 
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)) * 10 
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1)) * 1 as the_value
    from a
)
select c from x where the_value = (select MAX(the_value) from x)
```

In software development, it is typical to find a minor version number that has two digits in it, the version's number don't have any bearing with number's value, thus version 1.12 is greater than 1.5; to compensate for that, you must *pad* the digits adequately:

```
    -- Use this, the query above is not future-proof :-)
with a as
(
    select * from (values
    ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)
),
x as 
(
    select c, 
       convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)) * 100*100*100 
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)) * 100*100 
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1)) * 100 as the_value
    from a
)
select c, the_value from x   
order by the_value
```

Output:

```
2.1.4   2010400
2.1.5   2010500
2.1.12  2011200
2.2.1   2020100
```

If you don't take that into consideration(as with the following query):

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
    ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)
),
x as 
(
    select c, 
       convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)) * 100
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)) * 10
       + convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1)) * 1 as the_value
    from a
)
select c, the_value from x   
order by the_value;


    -- KorsG's answer has a bug too
with a as
(
    select * from (values
    ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)
),
x as 
(
    select c, 
       CAST(REPLACE(c, '.', '') AS int) as the_value
    from a
)
select c, the_value from x   
order by the_value
```

Those two queries will yield the same (incorrect) output:

```
c           the_value
2.1.4   214
2.1.5   215
2.2.1   221
2.1.12  222
```

The 2.2.1 and 2.1.12's value overlapped. That also happens when you merely remove the dots and directly convert the resulting string to int. 2.1.12 become two thousand one hundred twelve, 2.2.1 become two hundred twenty one.  2.2.1 is greater than 2.1.12, not less than

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 DOWNLOADPATH
from YourTable
order by cast(parsename(VERSIONNUMBER, 3) as int) desc,
         cast(parsename(VERSIONNUMBER, 2) as int) desc,
         cast(parsename(VERSIONNUMBER, 1) as int) desc
```

Comment: Excellent misappropriation of an existing function :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of multiplying each digit group, you can use ranking:

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
        ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') 
    ) as b(c)     
),
x as
(
select c, 
    Ranking = RANK() over(order by convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)), convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)), convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1))) 
from a
)
select * from x 
    order by ranking
```

Yields:

```
c   Ranking
2.1.4   1
2.1.5   2
2.1.12  3
2.2.1   4
```

Final query:

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
        ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') 
    ) as b(c)     
),
x as
(
select c, 
    Ranking = RANK() over(order by convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)), convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)), convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1))) 
from a
)
select * 
from x  
where Ranking = (select MAX(ranking) from x)
```

Output:

```
c   Ranking
2.2.1   4
```

Another simple approach, sort descending then just get the first row:

```
with a as
(
    select * from (values
        ('2.1.4 '), ('2.1.12'), ('2.1.5'), ('2.2.1') ) as b(c)     
),
x as
(
select c, 
    Ranking = RANK() 
        over(order by 
            convert(int,PARSENAME(c,3)) desc, 
            convert(int,PARSENAME(c,2)) desc, 
            convert(int,PARSENAME(c,1)) desc) 
from a
)
select * 
from x  
where Ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can lever the `HIERARCHYID` datatype.

```
SELECT VersionNumber, DownloadPath
FROM (VALUES
    ('1.1.2','a.com'),
    ('1.1.3','b.com'),
    ('2.1.4','c.com'),
    ('2.1.5','d.com'),
    ('2.2.1','e.com')        
     ) AS T(VersionNumber, DownloadPath)
ORDER  BY CAST('/' + VersionNumber + '/' AS HIERARCHYID) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it ain't pretty - I would definitely consider changing the way you store version numbers.

```
concat( 
right(concat(repeat("0",5), substring_index(VERSIONNUMBER,".",1)),5),
right(concat(repeat("0",5), substring_index(substring_index(VERSIONNUMBER,".",2),".",-1)),5),
right(concat(repeat("0",5), substring_index(VERSIONNUMBER,".",-1)),5))
```

Basically it turns `"1.24.937"` into `"000010002400937"`, which then sorts properly as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like @Mikael's version, but obviously that's not quite as portable to other RDBMSes...

How about this? Quick and dirty, and works for three-number versions (as given in your example.)

The hack here is to realise that "2.59", for example, is a valid number, just not a valid integer, so you only have to split the string in one place -- you want the major version number, and the rest. This is hideous, but when it sprang to mind, I figured I'd share it, as it is at least *short* and hideous.

```
SELECT 
   TOP 1 downloadpath 
FROM 
   version_table 
ORDER BY 
   CAST(LEFT(VERSIONNUMBER, CHARINDEX( '.', VERSIONNUMBER) - 1) AS INTEGER) DESC,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(VERSIONNUMBER, CHARINDEX( '.', VERSIONNUMBER) + 1, 100) AS FLOAT) DESC
```

Of course, the real answer is to change your database design to either split out the version numbers or include a build number or something like that...

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT downloadpath FROM TABLE
WHERE versionnumber = (SELECT MAX(VersionNumber) FROM TABLE)
```

There might be a prettier way to do it as well.

Comment: As far as I know, MAX only works with ints, so can't do max for 3.1.4.

Comment: @Davvek: and what about 3.10.4 and 3.2.5? What order then?

Comment: You're right, it will only work assumming single-digits on each versioning level.