# SQL compare strings having version as value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split a string and return greatest in mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855588/split-a-string-and-return-greatest-in-mssql)

I need to compare strings which have version value, for example:
string1 = 2.3.4
string2 = 2.5.6
Now in the above case i need to check which string version is greater?

Comment: I think that more information is needed to complete this compare. Will the version always be a single digit at each level? `X.X.X`? Or will it ever be `XX.X.X`?

Comment: Version could be more than one digit, for example it could be 22.143.1123 or it could also be 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

in sql server:

```
Declare @string1 varchar(10)
Declare @string2 varchar(10)

SET @string1='2.3.4'
SET @string2='2.5.6'

select CASE WHEN convert(int,replace(@string1,'.','')) > convert(int,replace(@string2,'.','')) then @string1 else @string2 end GreaterVersion
```

Comment: Good logic... but i think the result goes wrong for '10.9' and '1.80'. Please confirm from your side.

Answer (score -1):

you can try strcmp

```
CASE
 WHEN str1 = str2 THEN 0
 WHEN str1 < str2 THEN -1
 WHEN str1 > str2 THEN 1
  ELSE NULL --one of the strings is NULL so won't compare (added on edit)
END
```

Comment: This breaks down quickly due to the nature of lexical sorting if not always in the exact single-digit x.y.z format.

Comment: That's great for comparing strings, but not version numbers.